# Remember window layout on multiple monitors on Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, multi-monitor

I have been using linux Mint 17.3 with Mate desktop for quite a bit now.  One of the thing I absolutely love is that it remembers layout of windows for multiple monitor configurations.  For example, in my normal desktop setup, I have my laptop on a docking station with 3 monitors attached to it - and my application windows are spread over these three monitors.  When I undock the laptop, all windows move to the laptop display.  When I connect the laptop back to the docking station, all windows are restored to their previous positions on the three monitors.

The other day I tried switching to Cinnamon desktop, per a colleague's recommendation - it does look nicer and works smoother, but it does not remember window position on multiple monitors.  In the scenario above, when I plug the laptop back to the docking station, all windows stay on the primary display.

For me, this feature (or rather lack thereof) alone is enough to abandon Cinnamon and go back to Mate, as I have a lot of application windows open at any given time (15-20 is the norm) and I dock/undock the laptop several times a day in the course of my normal work.  I can't afford to spend time rearranging windows every time I dock the laptop.

So, the question is, how can I make Cinnamon remember the windows position on multiple monitors and then restore it when I dock the laptop again?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't automated this, but `wmctrl` let's you record window positions and also set them. `xdotool` might also work. Here are commands to restore and place windows:

Record: `wmctrl -lG > ${rcfile}`

Place:

```
while read row; do
  IFS=" " read id g x y w h _ <<< ${row}
  wmctrl -ir ${id} -e 0,${x},${y},${w},${h}
done < ${rcfile}
```

Comment: very interesting, do you know of any GUIs for this?

Comment: https://github.com/p-e-w/argos or https://askubuntu.com/questions/475081/how-to-create-a-launcher-to-execute-a-terminal-command

Answer (score 1):

This has been an ongoing issue with Cinnamon and to my knowledge this functionality still isn't available out of the box.

[This thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=127245) mentions a program called [gDevilspie](https://launchpad.net/gdevilspie) that supposedly allows you to configure the default window positions. I don't have any experience with it, though.